# Issues with google

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible, depending on the environment of the company, that some features of Google are non-existent? I tried some functions with my personal email and it works; but, in a professional environment it doesn't work.

```
function getDataForSearch() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("PEP FORMULAR");
  return ws.getRange(6, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 6).getValues();
  
}

var data;

function setDataForSearch(){

      
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
          data = dataReturned.slice();
        }).getDataForSearch();
        

      }
      
      function search(){

        var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
        var searchWords = searchInput.split(/\s+/);
        //var searchColumns = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
        var searchColumns = [0];
        //and

        var resultsArray = searchInput == "" ? [] : data.filter(function(r){

          return searchWords.every(function(word){
            return searchColumns.some(function(colIndex){
              return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1;
            });
          });
    
        });

        var searchResultsBox =  document.getElementById("searchResults");
        var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
        var template = templateBox.content;

        searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

        resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

          var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
          var typeInitiativeColumn = tr.querySelector(".type-initiative");
          var pepRefColumn = tr.querySelector(".pep-ref");
          var projectNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".project-name");

          pepRefColumn.textContent = r[0];
          typeInitiativeColumn.textContent = r[2];
          projectNameColumn.textContent = r[5];
          searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);

        });

      }
```

This code works but, when I try to reproduce it in a professional environment, the function `setDataForSerach()` is not able to get the data from the function `getDataForSearch()` and make a copy.

Comment: What kind of issues? What is this "some function"? Please add a [mcve] so we might be able to help

Comment: Functions like slice() and fliter() . I created a CRUD menu in App script and when I tried to do the same thing in my professionnal environnment it doesn't work.

Comment: You should really [edit] your post with an [mre]

Comment: _"reproduce it in a professional environment"_ what do you mean? What's a "professional" environment?

Comment: professionnal means  with an enterprise who used google environnment.

Comment: Do you mean a G-suite subscription?

Comment: yes, exactly !!!